# the perfect way of implementing javascript 'outerHTML' as exactly native way

Tags: javascript, outerhtml, es5-shim

We all know we can use outerHTML like these two way:

```
<h1></h1>
<p>I am superstar.</p>

//first way
var star = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
var starOuterHTML = star.outerHTML;
alert(starOuterHTML);//this output: '<p>I am superstar.</p>'

//second way
var star = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
star.outerHTML = '<h1>I am superstar.<h1>';////these two above sentences are both h1 element now,that's we have two h1 element
```

but due to some browsers do not implement it, so i decided to make an implementation by myself, these are all what i have done by myself now:

```
if(!Element.outerHTML){
      Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype,'outerHTML',{
          value: function(){
              var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
              wrapper.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true));
              return wrapper.innerHTML;                    
          },
          writable: true,
          enumerable: false,
          configurable: false
      })  
  }
```

now as you know it's the implementaion of the first way, but there is something wrong here(i need to code like: star.outerHTML() rather than star.outerHTML if we use the above code), if we want our implementation to just like the build-in outerhtml way, which i will talk about later.

and i have no idea how to implement the second way of outerHMTL property of Element?

AS i searched the web and the books i have, i found the following implementation of outerHTML in unsupported browsers:

```
          (function(){

        if(document.createElement('div').outerHTML) return;

        function outerHTMLGetter(){
          var container = document.createElement('div');
          container.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true));
          return container.innerHTML;  
        }

        function outerHTMLSetter(value){
               var container = document.createElement('div');
               container.innerHTML = value;
               while(container.firstChild){
                this.parentNode.insertBefore();
              }
              this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
        }


        if(Object.defineProperty){
          Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'outerHTML',{
            get: outerHTMLGetter,
            set: outerHTMLSetter,
            enumerable:false,
            configurable: true
          });
        }else{
          Element.prototype.__defineGetter__('outerHTML', outerHMTLGetter);
          Element.prototype.__defineSetter__('outerHTML', outerHMTLSetter);

        }
      }());
```

Yeah, we can implement it using the code above I have searched, but if we use the above code, including my own code, we are using function.   However, outerHTML is a property of the Element Object, not function, and i need to implement it completely as the build-in way, so that we can use it even we drop our implementation code in the future when all browsers implement the outHTML property without changing any of our code.

the build-in way: star.outerHTML
the above code way(not good): 
   *star.outerHTML()
   star.outerHTML(value)*

so any ideas to make my own written code perfectly?
Thankks

Comment: _"some browsers do not implement it"_ -> some [_really old_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML#Browser_compatibility) browsers don't support it - are you sure you need to support those browsers?

Comment: I don't get case 2, according to the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Parsing/#widl-Element-outerHTML) the property `outerHTML` 'Returns a fragment of HTML or XML that represents the element and its contents', Where does `h1` come into play with `star.outerHTML`, given your html.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I wanna know how to implement such property in javascript build- in way, so I make it as an example^_^

Comment: @birdspider It's for example purpose. And I made it. Is there anything wrong with it? Thanks?

Comment: @Kaiido outHTML is defined only for Element nodes, which is said in the book of Javascript , the definite guide, where am I missing? Thanks?

Comment: @Kaiido I donot get it, can you explain more? Thanks^_^

Comment: @franklee , by which reason is `star.outerHTML = '<h1>I am superstar.<h1>'` (h1!) in your second example - given that star = 'p'

Comment: @birdspider, it's for assigning the html string '<h1>I am superstar.<h1>' to star.outerHTML so that star's element becomes the h1 element

Comment: @franklee ah well, I missinterpreted that a an expectation